# Jenkins Multi-configuration project fail treshold

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins

We have a parameterized Multi-configuration project which runs with 3 axis

browser
client 
test

on a java Unit test with test stories

Problem is due the legacy/system load on the server the pages the tests are calling sometimes run on timeouts, or selenium just bugs up because it is running with the crap IE.

And that test fails.

The thing is then marked as red if ONE of them failed. Problem is we have like 40 tests and some are bound to go bad...

Is there a way to configure so the build is ok as long 2-3 tests fail?
Ideal would be to be able to define that a Axis (browser) has to fail for the same test.. but im happy with either.